# Django: how to define a global property for request?

Tags: django

There are some global properties in `request` in every view (for example `request.user`).

I want to define my own global property for `request`. How to do that and in what place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write a custom context processor.
Check the djangodocs for info or see a sample http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.com/2009/01/add-context-processor-for-your-django.html
.

Comment: That's how you get a variable into a template, but context processors do not work on request objects themselves. You need to use middleware for that.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: right, from the description I guessed he wanted a context processor :) +1 for the comment.